# Модальное окно, как сделать чтобы страница не дергалась при открытии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код

```js
function showModalWin() {
  var fixed = document.body;

  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  var darkLayer = document.createElement('div');
  darkLayer.id = 'shadow';
  document.body.appendChild(darkLayer);
  var modalWin = document.getElementById('popupWin');
  modalWin.style.display = 'block';
  fixed.style.overflow = "hidden";
  darkLayer.onclick = function() {
    darkLayer.parentNode.removeChild(darkLayer);
    modalWin.style.display = 'none';
    fixed.style.overflow = "auto";
    return false;
  };

  button.onclick = function() {
    darkLayer.parentNode.removeChild(darkLayer);
    modalWin.style.display = 'none';
    fixed.style.overflow = "auto";
    return false;
  };
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
}

.modalwin {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px outset gray;
  background: wheat;
  top: 20%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #383838;
  transition: 1s;
}

#shadow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 32px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  content: ' ';
  height: 25px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Вызвать окно" class="showModal" onclick="showModalWin()">
  </form>

  <div style="text-align: center" id="popupWin" class="modalwin">
    <form class="modalform">
      <a href="#" class="modalbutton close" id="button"></a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

При появлении/исчезновении модального окна содержимое страницы дергается из за исчезновения/появления скрола, хотелось бы, чтобы этого дергания не было, без js библиотек, но ума не приложу как реализовать

Comment: Когда открываете модальное окно - добавляете содержимому страницы padding с правой стороны равный размеру скролбара.

Comment: Если тебя смущает то, что полоска скрола появляется и исчезает, то убери везде `fixed.style.overflow = "auto" & overflow: hidden !important;`.  Но если тебе интересно чужое мнение, то у тя такой ужас, а не код, если выразться прилично...

Comment: Это к тя упрощенный вариант примера или ты решил, что для открытия мод окна нужна форма?

Comment: Просто упрощенный вар

Comment: Ок.........................